# How to show available key combinations and their descriptions, to learn about them

Tags: emacs, elisp

## Searching for a better tool to learn key combination in Emacs

Though, I have used a package "guide-key" before, I like how "which-key" looks and feel.
However, I encountered one problem. In contrast with "guide-key", it can also show the next key combination.

For example, 
type "C-x" then there is also "C-f" description.

Is there anyway we can configure "which-key" to do similar things?

Comment: I don't know which version of `which-key` you're using, but the one I just tried does exactly what you're asking for. In fact that seems to be its entire purpose.

Comment: @phils Do you know how to bring those suggestions up? It seems like they're hidden due to many single key suggestions before it.

Comment: Well if the frame is too small to show all the results, the output tells you to press `C-h` for help *and paging*. `C-h n` displays the next page of results. `C-x` naturally has a *lot* of results, as it's a very heavily-utilised prefix.

Comment: Your heading "*Searchiing for a better tool to learn key combinations*" is a different request from your "*Is there anyway we can configure `which-key`*" to provide additional information. Which is it? (I edited the title to reflect your heading, assuming you are asking for how to get this info, in Emacs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for a better tool to show you *what keys you can use* to complete a key sequence that you have started (by using one or more prefix keys).  You want to also have access to or immediately see *additional info* about those key completions, e.g., what the resulting key sequence does and what command it is bound to.  You might also want to have the tool help you complete the key sequence, to *invoke it*.

The [key completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion) provided by library [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) does all of this, and more.

It is available all the time - just hit `S-TAB` to complete any key sequence. You can also hit `S-TAB` at the top level, to see all of the possible key sequences in the current context and complete any of them to invoke it.

Each key-sequence completion candidate shows you the remainder of the key sequence, followed by `=`, followed by the command the sequence is bound to.  You can type input to match either or both parts of this candidate, and matching can be as simple or fancy as you like (regexp etc.).

As you type, the set of matching candidates is filtered to correspond.  At any time you can also cycle among the current candidates.  As you cycle, a description of the current candidate (which is highlighted) is shown in the mode line of the buffer (`*Completions*`) where they are listed.

If you want more information about the current candidate that this one-liner, just hit `C-M-RET` to pop up buffer `*Help*` with the complete documentation of the key sequence and its command.

Hit `RET` to choose the current candidate to invoke it. Or just hit `C-g` if you don't want to invoke any key now, but you just wanted info about the currently available keys.

Prefix keys that are available in the current context are also listed as candidates.  E.g., prefix key `4` is available as a candidate when you are completing prefix key `C-x`.  You can navigate up, down, and around the entire hierarchy of all key sequences by choosing prefix-key candidates or by choosing the candidate `..`, which goes back up.

Candidate key sequences are highlighted differently if they are local bindings (e.g. local to the current mode) or if they are prefix keys.

You can sort the candidates in various ways: prefix keys first, local keys first, command-name alphabetical order, and so on.